# MySQL special character concat_ws

Tags: mysql, utf-8, concat-ws

I want the following Character **»** to show when i do a query but I keep getting the following **Â»**

Here is my query:

```
SELECT CONCAT_WS(' » ',t2.`description`,t1.`description`) AS pages_structure
```

My Database is set to utf8_general_ci

Comment: possible duplicate of [UTF-8 all the way through](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through)

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that your client character set is not utf8. Run this to find out if that's the case:

```
show variables like 'character_set_client';
```

Then you could change it like this to test if it fixes your problem:

```
set character_set_client = 'utf8';
```

You may need to make that change in your /etc/my.cnf as well.

Comment: Done all 3 had no affect. I restarted MySQL after config change.

Comment: Run this to confirm that you are using utf8 across the board: `show variables like 'character\_set\_%';`

Answer (score 0):

Managed to fix the issue by updating to MySQL version 5.5.